# DynamoDB Streams - Multiple child shards

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, sharding, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Does anyone have any information about how much throughput DynamoDB Streams can handle before it splits a single shard into multiple child shards?

I understand the single child approach with the four hour write timespan etc, but have not been able to find any information or "mock" a scenario where the shards break into multiple children. From anyone's experience is this rare or is the throughput required to force this functionality just huge?